# Bitmap-analysis code works pre-2.2, not 2.2

Tags: android, bitmap, compatibility

I'm creating "maps" for a game I'm making, and it's working fine on <=Android 2.1, but 2.2 is causing problems.

I'm not sure if this is a common method, so I'll explain what I'm doing. First, I draw the map which the user is going to see then I draw a map of identical size with nothing but white and pink (0xffFF006E). Anywhere I draw the pink color is an area/boundary I don't want the player to be able to enter/cross.

So, in-game, the regular map is constantly being drawn and the "bordermap" with the pink color is loaded into a Bitmap (but never actually drawn). To see if the player is *attempting* to cross a border, I check the player's x,y pos against the bordermap:

```
private boolean overBorder(int x, int y){

   //The int 'COLOR_border' is predefined as 0xffFF006E
if(mPlayerDirection == UP && mMapBorders.getPixel(x, y-mPlayerHeight/2) == COLOR_border)return true;
if(mPlayerDirection == DOWN && mMapBorders.getPixel(x, y+mPlayerHeight/2) == COLOR_border)return true;
if(mPlayerDirection == LEFT && mMapBorders.getPixel(x-mPlayerWidth/2, y) == COLOR_border)return true;
if(mPlayerDirection == RIGHT && mMapBorders.getPixel(x+mPlayerWidth/2, y) == COLOR_border)return true;

   //If those fail, false    
   return false;
}
```

If that code returns true, I stop the player. Like I said, this works excellently pre-2.2. If anyone has any insight on how to fix 2.2 compatibility I would appreciate it greatly.

Comment: Oh, sorry I should've posted that.. The player just walks right over the bordered areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe related to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4710 , and colors being reported as pre-multiplied or post-multiplied.  Are you sure your bitmap has an alpha channel?  From that post:

> I think I may have found the answer to
>   my own problem.  I've only tried it
>   with some test code, but it seems it
>   may be the solution.  I was calling
>   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources
>   res, int id) to load a bitmap.  A call
>   to Bitmap.hasAlpha() returned false. 
>   So, I went into my bitmap with
>   Paint.NET, erased some colors, and
>   re-saved.  The hasAlpha() method now
>   returns true.  The getPixel() and
>   setPixel() method appear to return
>   values more like they did in 1.6.  So,
>   I presume that the problem is not in
>   2.0, but was actually in 1.6 - in that it thought the bitmap had a
>   transparency color set when it didn't.
>   I'll test tonight and report back my
>   findings.

Comment: This stuff is a bit over my head, but if it helps I ran it in 2.1 and 2.2 and hasAlpha() returned false both times. Is this the problem?

Comment: Oh, I got it. I added some transparent regions to the map and saved it, now it's working in 2.2. Now I have a new problem, it's incredibly slow in 2.2 but same speed in 2.1 O_o